# Find time complexity of the following algorithm - isBunkerArray()?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, time-complexity, primes

What is the **time complexity** of **isBunkerArray()** function below. Note that it is calling **isPrime()** function for every odd number in array till any odd number in array is followed by prime

```
static int isBunkerArray(int[] arr) {
    int bunker = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
        if (arr[i] % 2 != 0) {
            if (isPrime(arr[i + 1]) == 1) {
                bunker = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return bunker;
}

private static int isPrime(int n) {
    if (n < 2)
        return 0;

    for (int i = 2; i <= n / 2; i++) {
        if (n % i == 0)
            return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the value of each member of the array is `W`. The time complexity of `isPrime` is `O(W)`. And in the worst case, it will be called for each member of the array with size `n`. Hence, `isBunnkerArray` is in `O(W*n)`. Notice that, you can implement `isPrime` more efficiently in `O(\sqrt{W})`.

Comment: can you share that O(\sqrt{W}) approach

Comment: @NirmalSilwal It's simple. Just change `n / 2` in the isPrime to `sqrt{n}`. It works because if `n % i != 0` as `n = i * q + r` and `r > 0`, you will not need to check `(n-r)/i`. Hence, you can show that the maximum value that you need to check is `sqrt{n}` (not 'n/2`).